# I have servers running applications outside a VPC without a static IP range, what is a secure way to connect to databases hosted in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture

For example, let's say I use cloudflare workers as serverless compute, how would I securely make requests from cloudflare workers to my AWS MySQL instance? (It doesn't have to be cloudflare workers, that's just an example)

One approach I can think of is to have some api in front of the MySQL instance but how should I implement authorization between the API and the serverless application if I were to take this approach?

Comment: VPN tunnel or SSH tunnel?

Comment: If you really want to provide a public API you should look into API Gateway in AWS. It gives you different options for authentication / authorization, incl. API keys, IAM integration, Cognito integration, third party integration, etc.